# How would somebody reduce the amount of Nuxt pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Imagine you are developing a big-scale nuxt app that has 100 routes. what is the best solution for managing routes (not micro-frontend) in this app?

Comment: What do you mean by managing? This question is too broad and is lacking details. Isn't the routing directories enough as of management?

Comment: Is it normal you have 100 components in pages directory? this is an interview question that someone asked me and i suggested break app into two or three or more apps based on micro-frontend. now i want to know is there a better way?

Comment: Can you give more details on what would those 100 components be? Can't some of them be dynamic? Did your interviewer gave you more details?

Comment: as you know in nuxt, components that are in pages directory are our pages and routes. imagine we have too many routes such: /user/id, post/id, /about, /login and ... and we have 100 number of routes. is there any way to manage better? or should add all of them in pages directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by this?

> or should add all of them in pages directory?`

Here, we're talking about **pages** only, right? So `/user/id`, `/post/id` and so on?
If it's the case, you could have a `/_entity/id` or even a `/_entity/_slug` for more flexibility (with `_entity` being either `user` or `post` etc...).
If you have a lot of various pages like `/about`, `/our-team`, `/careers` and so on, I guess that those will need their own SEO, content and are totally legit.

I don't really see why this would be an issue at all. It will be properly organized, scalable and will not have too much abstraction neither (which is important IMO).

You could also export some of those pages into `.md` files thanks to `nuxt/content` and import them into the pages. Like the Nuxt documentation [is doing](https://github.com/kissu/nuxtjs.org/tree/master/content/en).

If you **really need** to simplify those, yeah you could make the whole templates dynamic and generate the markup on fly. This could introduce some huge complexity that may not be needed IMO.
Also, layouts, slots and render functions can be a solution too I guess.

---

I'm not sure if micro-frontends (sounds like a buzz word for me) are actually several instances on Nuxt one next to another (sounds like a terrible idea if hosted under the same domain) or just "component-ization" of your non monolithic fullstack app (pretty much how we build websites for few years already).
But for me, if a project do have 100 `pages`, it is totally fine.

Of course, having some hardcoded `/blog/post/1`, `/blog/post/2` is bad (lol) but a large app could be totally fine. It may create some issues regarding the build time and so on, but this is another subject and relies more of the way you do generate the project.

So yeah, if your interviewer wanted to go deeper than those approaches, you would need more details from him to exactly know what are the challenges and what could be used.

---

TLDR: as far as I know, no frameworks aim to reduce the number of pages because this is not an issue by itself. 10k Nuxt pages will not make your `/about` one slower by any means (if it does, the issue is elsewhere).

Comment: Tnx for complete answer. i agree with you. having too many routes wouldn't be issue and it's ok.